# What is the source that says the Jinn live for 500 years?

Tags: hadith, jinn

While watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22EgNJu65vs) starting at timestamp 41:03, I heard aleem [Dr. Omar Zaid](https://zaidpub.com/) mention that the Jinn live for 500 years. Since he is a notable revert aleem wıth extensive knowledge of previous scriptures as well as Islamic sources, I am sure this statement about Jinn is based on authentic sources, but I have never heard of this before.

What source(s) assert that Jin live for 500 years?

Comment: The video you are referring to is about 50 minutes long, you didn't state where he made this claim. And this convert states at the beginning that one needs to look beyond the qur'an which may mean that this statement might come from non-Islamic sources. Whether he is a 'Alim or not is a matter I don't know as I don't know him at all. Expect with some doubtful sources I've never heard of an Islamic source quoting a lifespan of Jinn.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I updated the question with the timestamp.  He mentioned it in his other videos as well.  I don't know if the word "jinn" is ever mentioned outside of Islam, much less their lifespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any authoritative source which mentions the average lifespan of a Jinn (see [islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/78165/%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86-%D9%88%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%87%D9%85-%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86)). Although it is generally believed that they have long lifespans. For example in the exegesis of [46:29-30](https://legacy.quran.com/46/29-30), a story is recorded that the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ met a jinn who had met Moses عليه السلام  and other  prophets. And in a [report](https://sunnah.com/muslim/introduction/17) from Abdullah ibn Amr it is implied that jinn from the time of Solomon عليه السلام are still alive.

Answer (score 0):

Every Human that gets born then another jinn gets born. Every human that were born from the time of Prophet Adam till now, the jinn that were born the same time are still alive because the jinns live until the day of judgement because Iblis asked Allah to live until the day of judgement the time he didn't listen to Allah and Allah accepted that so all jinns live until the day of judgement.